# How to ignore certain folders in HG?

Tags: mercurial

I have my project folder - Project.  In Project I have other sub projects - SUBPROJECT1, SUBPROJECT2, SUBPROJECT3.

In each sub project I have folders, among which I have BIN and OBJ.  However, I want the latter to be ignored such that when I commit I don`t have the changes made to BIN and OBJ.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to edit your `.hgignore` file, and include the following lines:

```
glob:bin\
glob:obj\
```

You probably want at least these other things as well:

```
glob:*.user
glob:*.suo
glob:_ReSharper.*\
```

There's other examples out there of more complete `.hgignore` files.

Comment: I have more than one project in the solution,how do I ignore the bin and obj of the projects?

Comment: Did you try just adding the two I specified?

Answer (score 0):

With [`.hgignore`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore).