# How to ignore some folders in HG?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Starting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496967/how-to-ignore-certain-folders-in-hg),
I'm wrestling with this right now. I've got two folders: Source and SQL. Source has multiple project folders. The project folders in Source and SQL have bin folders. I want to ignore all files in bin folders under Source, but not under SQL. I thought one of these might do the trick:

```
glob:Source\*\bin\
glob:Source\*\bin
glob:Source\*\bin\*
glob:Source\*\bin*
glob:Source*\bin\
glob:Source\*bin\
```

But no dice on all of the above.

It seems I'll have to enter a  line for each folder under Source where I expect to have a bin folder (and then update my .hgignore file whenever I add a new project).

```
glob:Source\Project1\bin\
glob:Source\Project2\bin\
#etc
```

If this is not the case, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried a regexp:

```
syntax: regex
^Source/.*/bin
```

Also, do remember that anything you've already added isn't affected by ignore rules, so you need the files to be untracked to test this stuff.

Lastly, consider making each project a separate repo -- that's the standard advice in DVCS land be it Mercurial or git.  In svn multiple projects in the same repo isn't such a bad idea because you can have different parts of the working directory updated to different revisions, but with a DVCS all files are updated/checkedout to the same revision, which makes putting multiple Projects in the same repo a hassle in general and a really bad idea in some circumstances.

Comment: A few tweaks I'd make, first one being just personal preference. Having tooled around with the hgignore file quite a bit, I find the declaration of the syntax on the same line as the pattern to be best for making lots of edits. Also, making the b in bin not case sensitive may be necessary in the future. And finally, put a slash at the end to prevent folders named binSomething from getting caught. But I like the slash after Source and the beginning of line marker. I can't verify this will work right now, but this seems optimal:

    re:^Source/.*/[Bb]in/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my .hgignore file, my slashes seem to to be the other way around (a forwrad slash instead of a backslash). i.e:

```
glob:*/bin/*
```

Try that maybe?

Comment: Close, but that will ignore bin folders in SQL as well as Source. Is there a glob command that will ignore bin folders in some folders but not others? This doesn't work either:

    glob:Source/*/bin/*

Comment: Nope, neither of those worked because I have bin folders under project folders under Source: Source/Project1/bin, Source/Project2/bin, Source/some/path/that/is/arbitrarily/long/bin, etc

Comment: Aplogies, I mis-read the question, I have created a folder called 'Test' and in that is a text file called 'hello' and also another folder called bin with a textfile called 'Ignore'. The following worked for me: glob:Test/*/bin/* (hello was visible in the commit and ignore was not). I am using tortoise HG v2.05. I see that this is the same as what you posted in the first comment so not sure why it does not work for you. Are you using tortoise hg?

Comment: Hmm, that's really odd that it works for you and not me. I am using tortoiseHg 2.1.3 (on a 64 bit Vista, if that makes any difference).

At any rate, I found a regex that does the trick:

    re:Source.*/[Bb]in/